# Selecting a structure via IF statement

Tags: c, if-statement, structure, ansi-c

I am trying to select one of two possible ANSI C expressions using an IF statement.  Each expression works fine by itself, eg...

```
wb_Parameters *WeightLimits = set100Parameters();
```

but when they're selected via an IF eg...

```
if (strcmp(CurrentAircraft->PhenomType,"100") == 0) 
    wb_Parameters *WeightLimits = set100Parameters();
else
    wb_Parameters *WeightLimits = set300Parameters();
```

I get the error message "Use of undeclared identifier 'WeightLimits'." What do I need to do to make this work inside an IF statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WeightLimits goes out of scope after the if statement. To avoid that, declare it before the if:

```
wb_Parameters *WeightLimits;
if (strcmp(CurrentAircraft->PhenomType,"100") == 0)
    WeightLimits = set100Parameters();
else
    WeightLimits = set300Parameters();
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I spent hours on this and you helped me in two minutes. What a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

First declare and then assign the right value:

```
wb_Parameters *WeightLimits = NULL;
if (strcmp(CurrentAircraft->PhenomType,"100") == 0) 
    WeightLimits = set100Parameters();
else
    WeightLimits = set300Parameters();
```

If you don't first declare it it goes out of scope and it can not be used anymore.

Comment: Why initialize if the very next thing you do is set the object value?

Comment: @pmg: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75039/why-declare-a-variable-in-one-line-and-assign-to-it-in-the-next/75040#75040

Comment: Ok: programmers are creatures of habits :)